# How do I style this img within a selector using variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to style an image that's being dynamically added into a div using a selector and while the styling does work (I tested), I can't figure out how to input a variable in as the value for the properties.

I've tried all types of syntax to try and make it work.

```
function addMole() {
    var xCord = myRandomX();
    var yCord = myRandomY();
    $("#gamespace").append("<img src=img/mole.png style=top:yCord+px;left:xCord+px;/>"); 
    setTimeout("addMole()", 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Not only your append (+) characters are inside the string, you are also missing the quotes around the attributes

You need to either do

```
$("#gamespace").append("<img src='img/mole.png' style='top:" + yCord + "px;left:" + xCord+ "px;'/>");
```

or you can use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
$("#gamespace").append(`<img src='img/mole.png' style= 'top: ${yCord}px;left: ${xCord}px;'/>`);
```

please note the use of backticks instead of quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addMole() {
    var xCord = myRandomX();
    var yCord = myRandomY();
    $("#gamespace").append("<img src='img/mole.png' style='top:" + yCord + "px;left:" + xCord + "px;' />"); 
    setTimeout(addMole, 2000);
}
```

I have changed 2 lines.

1. Changed `setTimeout("addMole()", 2000);` with `setTimeout(addMole, 2000);`
2. Changed `$("#gamespace").append("<img src=img/mole.png style=top:yCord+px;left:xCord+px;/>");` with `$("#gamespace").append("<img src='img/mole.png' style='top:" + yCord + "px;left:" + xCord + "px;' />");`.

`setTimeout` expects function name in its first parameter which does not need to be added in Quotation. You can refer to this tutorial for a better explanation:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: [Please don't use or link to w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a line break isn't allowed when using single or double quoted strings. So that's giving a syntax error. They are allowed in `template strings.
You can use ${expression} inside these` template strings like this:
`Hello ${name}.` resulting in 'Hello Joshua'.

Secondly, you can just put in the name of the function addMole to setTimeout.

```
function addMole(){
  var xCord = myRandomX();
  var yCord = myRandomY();
  $("#gamespace").append(`<img src=img/mole.png style=top:${yCord}px;left:${xCord}px;/>`); 
  setTimeout(addMole, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `css()` method is simpler and easier to read in my opinion. Note that when numeric values passed to `top` and `left` the `'px'` will be added internally

```
function addMole() {
  var xCord = myRandomX();
  var yCord = myRandomY();
  var $img = $('<img>', {src: 'img/mole.png'}).css({top: yCord, left: xCord})
  $("#gamespace").append($img);
  setTimeout("addMole()", 2000);
}
```